# Windows identity foundation - sign out or update claims

Tags: c#, wif

I am using Windows Identity foundation to manage login to our site.

When a user logs in i am using some information in his request to put into the claims.
It is all working fine, but now I need to manage this scenario:

1. user is already logged in, athenticated and has a valid token.
2. But user decides to browses in again (via a redirect from another site)
3. So his information in his request is different.
4. **I want to either**

   - Sign him out - so that he naturally creates a new token with his new information
   - OR update his existing token.

So my question is:

1. How do i Sign out of Windows Identity foundation?
2. Or How do I update the existing claims?

I have tried this code:

```
  public void ExpireClaims(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
    {
        var module =
            httpContextBase.ApplicationInstance.Modules["WSFederationAuthenticationModule"] as
            WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        if (module == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        module.SignOut(true);
    }
```

But module is alway null.

and i tried this:

```
  public void FederatedSignOut(string replyUrl)
    {
        WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(null, new Uri(replyUrl));
    }
```

But i get a null reference execption when i do this.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially sign-out is just deleting the cookie so:

`FormsAuthentication.SignOut`

or

`FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut`

or

`FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie`

will work.

Or use the `FederatedPassiveSignInStatus` (should be in your Toolbox). Set the property `SignOutAction` to `FederatedSignOut` and the control will clear out your STS session as well.

Comment: thanks, excellent answer! I am using  FederatedAuthentication.SessionAutheticationModule.SignOut. I noticed that just using FormsAuthentication.SignOut still allows users to access the federated sites, just not the one that you were currently in. Will investigate the final option as well. Thanks again.

Comment: After all that, the above methods only signed me out of the current relying party. They did not sign me out of all the relying parties. I had to implement my own custom federated sign out in the sts. Here is a link to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228746/wif-federatedsignout-not-signing-user-out-all-sites

Comment: Also, i discovered you cant update the claims once you create the token.  From a security point of view that seems sensible behaviour!

Comment: Yes - to get the updated claims you have to log out and log back in.