# WIF - FederatedSignOut not signing user out all sites

Tags: wif

I am using Windows Identity Foundation. (With some MVC 2.0 sites)

I am having real problem signing someone out of all the sites protected by WIF.

It looks like my sign out is only signing people out on the current site.

This is my code

```
public void FederatedSignOut(string replyUrl)
       {             

        var authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(authModule.Issuer),  new Uri(replyUrl));
     }
```

After running this code i can still browse to any other sites that the user has visited.
But i am logged out of the site i signed out of.

Does federated log out work?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Federated Sign Out works, but not always :-). What STS are you using? (e.g. ADFS? your own?)

There's some introduction information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359102.aspx#sec9

Check out how our "mock" sts handles Sign Out.

Comment: Hi, we have our own login site which external users have to login to, and are then given the wif token.  I am calling the signout code from one of the relying party sites. I was expecting it to sign me out for all relying parties.

Comment: If you have your own STS, then it is your responsibility to implement the SSout for the other applications the user is logged in into. See the example I mention above for details.

Comment: I have added some code to our custom sts which upon logout, redirects to each relying party with the action you suggested - my redirect looks like this: return Redirect("                                   http://myrelyingparty?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0&wreply=http://mysts/logout/logout");               it was nice i could also add a reply url, so i could come back to the sts and clean the other the federated sites. Anyway, it seems to work! Im very pleased, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WIF has a FederatedPassiveSignInStatus control which does the work for you.

Essentially, this sends a "wa=wsignout1.0" WS-Federation command to the STS. However, the STS may not implement this. ADFS does.

Comment: thanks i will have a look at this control. From what i have read this afternoon, i am wondering if i might need to call all relying parties with that wa command to clean up.  its not as simple as it first looked!

Comment: I should add we run our sites behind a load balancer which has two nodes.  I was wondering if this could be causing sign out problems. thanks

Comment: Perhaps. The problem with NLB is that the RP may not be able to read the cookies since they are protected by the machine key. Sticky sessions are one answer. Vittorio's book (pg. 124) discusses using the SSL certificate as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> When signing out of my application to external sts , I signout of my application but still stay signed in ***`ntexternal sts OKTA`***

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;`

    // Native FederatedSignOut doesn't seem to have a way for finding/registering realm for singout, get it from the FAM
    string wrealm = string.Format("wtrealm={0}", fam.Realm);

    // Check where to return, if not set ACS will use Reply address configured for the RP
    string wreply = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reply) ? reply : (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fam.Reply) ? fam.Reply : null);

    // Create basic url for signout (wreply is set by native FederatedSignOut)
    string signOutUrl = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(fam.Issuer, null, wrealm);


    WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(signOutUrl), !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wreply) ? new Uri(wreply) : null);
```